# escaping jvm parameters in windows cmd

Tags: java, windows, cmd

How do I escape the following characters in windows cmd?

```
-Djava.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format="[%1$tc] %4$s: %5$s %6$s%n"
```

I tried

```
-Djava.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format="[\%1\$tc] \%4\$s: \%5\$s \%6\$s\%n"
```

However this results in a java usage error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From command line you should not have any problem with the indicated command, but inside batch files you need to escape (doubling them) the percent signs

```dos
... .format="[%%1$tc] %%4$s: %%5$s %%6$s%%n"
```

**note**: When I say you should not have any problem in command line, I don`t mean you can not have problems, you should not.

Inside batch files, the parser replaces any variable reference. If the variable does not exist it will simply remove it. So, as `%1` to `%9` are batch file arguments, your code is parsed as

```dos
format="[%1$tc] %4$s: %5$s %6$s%n"
         ^^............................ first argument to batch file
                ^^..................... fourth argument to batch file
                      ^^............... fifth argument to batch file
                           ^^.......... sixth argument to batch file
                               ^....... unpaired % - removed
```

If you don't pass arguments to the batch file this is converted to

```dos
format="[$tc] $s: $s $sn"
```

In command line this behaviour is different, if the variable does not exist, the parser simply leaves the variable as is in the command. In your case the parser will try to resolve it as

```dos
format="[%1$tc] %4$s: %5$s %6$s%n"
         ^......^ ...................... variable "1$tc] "
                      ^....^ ........... variable "5$s "
                               ^........ unpaired - leave
```

So, unless you have something like

```dos
set "1$tc] =data"
```

you *should* not have problems

Answer (score 1):

Please try these

```
Character to be escaped     Escape Sequence Remark
%                               %%      May not always be required in doublequoted strings, just try
[                               \[
]                               \]
```

Find full characters [here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php)